# How to convert feet and inches in fraction format to decimal?

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, fractions

I'm working with a dataframe that I've imported via pandas. I have a column that includes values of length that are in feet and inches formatted as a fraction.

I would like to do the following conversion:

```
Length           Length Decimal 
0'-10 11/64"     0.85
4'- 7 19/64"     4.61
0'- 3"           0.25
62'- 3 3/4"      62.31
58'- 5 43/64"    58.47
2'-11 13/16"     2.98
```

I imagine I would have to try to break out each segment of the string and convert them to decimal then add them all together. I have been using Excel for this task, so I'm unsure how to handle it in Python. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've tried replacing the characters of the string with nothing i.e. `df['Length'].replace('-','')` but this does not allow me to combine the individual components of the string into one decimal format. Is there a module that contains a function that will do this nearly automatically?

Comment: My expectation would be that far more than one replace is needed to evaluate the string. Here on SO the asking person is more than invited to participate in solving the problem. So, show us some effort!

Comment: Sure thing! Thought I'd see if there was an extra special, super duper way to do this without performing numerous instances of "replace"

Comment: Id say that regular expressions with capture groups might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex, with named groups as @KlausD. suggest like this:

```
df = df.assign(**df['Length'].str.extract(r"(?P<Feet>\d+)'-\s?(?P<Inches>\d+)\s?(?P<Num>\d+)?\/?(?P<Dem>\d+)?\"")\
                        .astype(float).fillna(0))
df['Length Decimal'] = df.eval("Feet + Inches / 12") + np.where(df.Num == 0,0,(df["Num"]/df["Dem"])/12)
df
```

Output:

```
          Length  Length Decimal   Dem  Feet  Inches   Num
0   0'-10 11/64"        0.847656  64.0   0.0    10.0  11.0
1   4'- 7 19/64"        4.608073  64.0   4.0     7.0  19.0
2         0'- 3"        0.250000   0.0   0.0     3.0   0.0
3    62'- 3 3/4"       62.312500   4.0  62.0     3.0   3.0
4  58'- 5 43/64"       58.472656  64.0  58.0     5.0  43.0
5   2'-11 13/16"        2.984375  16.0   2.0    11.0  13.0
```